# How to copy a category in a SEO friendly way?

Tags: category, url, url-rewrite, seo

I have a category "clothing" (showing in menu) with a subcategory "all clothing". Both has the same products, but the url (/clothing and /clothing/all-clothing) is different, so that I have duplicate content. How can I make the url of "all clothing" the same as the url of "clothing"?

Comment: Wouldn´t it be enough to just have the main category and remove the subcategory "all clothing"